# Installing libcurl and non-root user: need to configure where code looks for libcurl.so.4

Tags: c, gcc, root, libcurl

I've successfully installed libcurl on a system and a non-root user, using the following configure flags:

```
./configure --prefix=/path/to/lib --exec-prefix=/path/to/lib --bindir=/path/to/lib
```

Everything works running compilation as follows:

```
gcc -I/path/to/include -L/path/to/lib/ client.c -lcurl -o client
```

The issue comes when I try to run the resulting program. I get the following error:

```
client: error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've googled around a bit and found that it has been reported (and rejected) as a bug [here](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/tracker-2009-05/0014.html), but I'm still not clear how to resolve the issue. Using `ldconfig` as suggested in the response would require root permissions, which I obviously do not have.

Is there something I can do to make this all work? It seems like this should be simple, but if it is then I'm completely missing it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to rely on an environment variable, you can use [rpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath):

```
gcc -I/path/to/include -L/path/to/lib/ client.c -lcurl -Wl,-rpath,/path/to/lib -o client
```

This will hardcode `/path/to/lib` in the executable so that the dynamic linker will search for your `.so` there first.

(Please also note that in the general case, using `-rpath` is considered to be bad practice: if the RPATH directory is writable by anyone else than root, it can lead to security issues.)

Answer (score 1):

Set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to dynamically tell your program where to look for shared libraries. In your case, with Bourne/bash shell, you might do something like:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/too/lib
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$ ./client
```

See [Shared libraries HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html) for more information. Note also that generally, you shouldn't consider `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` a production solution: you'll eventually want to get your sysadmin to configure system load paths or install your library in the correct locations.

Comment: I wish I could mark both of yours as the right answer. The rpath option ended up being the best for this specific problem, but it's good to know I can use env variables to do the same thing.

Comment: I totallly forgot about `rpath`! @Schnouki has the right solution, you marked the right one. :-)